# Laravel Single Job Class dispatched multiple times with different parameters getting overwritten

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I'm using Laravel Jobs to pull data from the Stripe API in a paginated way. Basically, each job gets a "brand id" (a user can have multiple brands per account) and a "start after" parameter. It uses that to know which stripe token to use and where to start in the paginated calls (this job call itself if more stripe responses are available in the pagination). This runs fine when the job is started once.

But there is a use case where a user could add stripe keys to multiple brands in a short time and that job class could get called multiple times concurrently with different parameters. When this happens, whichever process is started last overwrites the others because the parameters are being overwritten to just the last called. So if I start stripe job with brand_id = 1, then job with brand_id = 2, then brand_id = 3, 3 overwrites the other two after one cycle and only 3 gets passed for all future calls.

How do I keep this from happening?

I've tried static vars, I've tried protected, private and public vars. I thought might be able to solve it with dynamically created queues for each brand, but this seems like a huge headache.

```
public function __construct($brand_id, $start_after = null)
    {
        $this->brand_id       = $brand_id;
        $this->start_after = $start_after;
    }

public function handle()
{
    // Do stripe calls with $brand_id & $start_after

    if ($response->has_more) {
    // Call next job with new "start_at".
        dispatch(new ThisJob($this->brand_id, $new_start_after));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you share your `ThisJob` Class code ?

Comment: I should have been more clear. The example code is ThisJob. The job is recursive in order to paginate through all the results of the Stripe API call.

Comment: This is odd. I have never heard of overrided jobs. Isn't what you do with the results that are overriden?

Answer (score 1):

According to Laravel [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues)

> if you dispatch a job without explicitly defining which queue it
>   should be dispatched to, the job will be placed on the queue that is
>   defined in the queue attribute of the connection configuration.

```
// This job is sent to the default queue...
dispatch(new Job);

// This job is sent to the "emails" queue...
dispatch((new Job)->onQueue('emails'));
```

However, pushing jobs to multiple queues with **unique names** can be especially useful for your use case.

The queue name may be any string that uniquely identifies the queue itself. For example, you may wish to construct the queue name based on the `uniqid()` and `$brand_id`.

E.g:

```
dispatch(new ThisJob($this->brand_id, $new_start_after)->onQueue(uniqid() . '_' . $this->brand_id));
```